# SpringBoot 3 CouchbaseTemplate Insertion failure: Nested attribute of generic 'T' type cannot be stored and must be converted

Tags: spring-boot, java-17, spring-data-couchbase, spring-boot-3

**Got the following error while trying to use parameterized class/ Document for couchbase**

> Attribute of type com.testing.couchbase.model.Address cannot be stored
> and must be converted.

- I created 2 different API on a [Controller](https://github.com/anilsilwal98/couchbaseProject/blob/main/src/main/java/com/testing/couchbase/controller/CouchBaseController.java) with same @Document [CouchbaseDoc](https://github.com/anilsilwal98/couchbaseProject/blob/main/src/main/java/com/testing/couchbase/model/SampleDoc.java): but one is using **String** type and one using customized type "**Address**".
- The first one works fine but not the second one.
- The same    customized type  "Address" is present as a part of field for
  the given object @Document [CouchbaseDoc](https://github.com/anilsilwal98/couchbaseProject/blob/main/src/main/java/com/testing/couchbase/model/SampleDoc.java) separately also which works fine for 1st API.

---

the dependency setup
with these 2 combination

- Spring: 3.1.6
- Spring data couchbase: 5.0.3

---

same thing works fine when used using old version of dependency. The dependency combination that used to work

- Spring: 2.7.14
- Spring data couchbase: 4.4.14

Expecting:
I was expecting the data to be able to update on couchbase DB without any issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1875. it is fixed in main and will be included in the next release scheduled for February 16.

fyi - you can open issues directly at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues